# Grouping by a range of values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is as following:

```
id | label_id | value
1  | 1        | 500
2  | 1        | 600
3  | 1        | 900
4  | 1        | 10000
5  | 1        | 300
6  | 2        | ...
....................
```

Now, I want to generate a query result such as:

```
caption        | count
Less than 500  | 1
500 to 900     | 2
Above 900      | 1
```

In short, I'm trying to partition the result set so it is grouped by a range of values.
Any ideas?

The partition groups obviously would be pre-defined, meaning I'd know ahead of time that my partition scheme should be: < 500, 500 - 900, 900+ and so forth.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select sum(case when value < 500 then 1 else 0 end) as [less than 500],
       sum(case when value >= 500 and value <= 900 then 1 else 0 end) as [500 to 900],
       sum(case when value > 900 then 1 else 0 end) as [above 900]
    from YourTable
```

**EDIT**: To address [Dalen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246429/dalen) concern from the comments below and provide output in the exact format given in the question:

```
select 'less than 500' as Caption, count(*) as Count
    from YourTable
    where value < 500
union all
select '500 to 900' as Caption, count(*) as Count
    from YourTable
    where value >= 500 and value <= 900
union all
select 'above 900' as Caption, count(*) as Count
    from YourTable
    where value > 900
```

And, for SQL Server 2005+, you could improve on this by leveraging UNPIVOT with my original query:

```
select Caption, Count
    from (select sum(case when value < 500 then 1 else 0 end) as [less than 500],
                 sum(case when value >= 500 and value <= 900 then 1 else 0 end) as [500 to 900],
                 sum(case when value > 900 then 1 else 0 end) as [above 900]
              from YourTable) t
unpivot (Count for Caption in ([less than 500], [500 to 900], [above 900])) p
```

Comment: but this solution isn't exactly what @Isaac asked for

Comment: @Dalen: Sometimes you've got to read between the lines a little. But, I'll post a second query to address your concern.

Comment: You have to deserve that +6 ;)

Comment: @Dalen: Feel free to make it +7 now. ;)

Comment: +1 for the `Unpivot` this only takes one pass through the data. The `UNION ALL` just needs `WHERE` clause then could use `COUNT(*)` though so they aren't doing complete table scans every time (assuming an index on `value`).

Comment: For SQl server 2000, we have to do table scan 3 times .... Or in other words as many groups i have ....

Comment: I guess we can use Cross join to do one one scan of data. I have posted my answer for reference ...

Answer (score 4):

i would introduce another table called _range, something like that:

```
label     |lower|upper  |
-------------------------
up to 500 |0    |500    |
500 to 1k |501  |1000   |
over 1k   |1001 |1000000|
```

the you can join it with your table (_data on my example) to get something like you asked:

```
SELECT _range.label,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM _range JOIN _data
   ON value >= lower and value <= upper
GROUP BY _range.label
```

result will be

```
label     |count|
-----------------
up to 500 |2    |
500 to 1k |2    |
over 1k   |1    |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when  value < 500 then 'Less than 500'
                when value >= 500 and value <= 900 then '500 - 900'
                else 'Above 900' end as caption, COUNT(*) as count
    from mytable
    group by case when  value < 500 then 'Less than 500'
                when value >= 500 and value <= 900 then '500 - 900'
                else 'Above 900' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select count(*) from TABLE where VALUE_FIELD between VALUE1 and VALUE2

run it for different value ranges.
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2000, where we do not have Unpivot ..... It will still have only one scan ..

```
SELECT 

 CASE WHEN T1.Group = 1 Then 'less than 500'
      WHEN T1.Group = 2 Then '500 to 900'
      WHEN T1.Group = 3 Then 'above 900' END as [Label],

 CASE WHEN T1.Group = 1 Then T.[less than 500]
      WHEN T1.Group = 2 Then T.[500 to 900]
      WHEN T1.Group = 3 Then T.[above 900] END as [Count]

FROM
(
  select sum(case when value < 500 then 1 else 0 end) as [less than 500],
         sum(case when value >= 500 and value <= 900 then 1 else 0 end) as [500 to 900],
         sum(case when value > 900 then 1 else 0 end) as [above 900]
    from YourTable
) T
CROSS JOIN 
(
   Select 1 as Group
    UNION ALL
   Select 2
    UNION ALL
   Select 3
) T1
```